# xslt: check the elements in XML file, add if expected elements are missing in it

Tags: xml, xslt, osb

I will get a fIXML message like below.

```
<FIXML v="4.4" xsi:schemaLocation="../../schema/fixml-main-4-4.xsd" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Main attr1="19000" attr2="10">
    <Hdr hattr1="ABC" hattr2="DEF"/>
    <Insert1 I1attr1 ="2008-08" I1attr2 ="20080810"/>
    <Insert2 I2attr1="A111C" I2attr2 ="123">
    <sub ID="1AC"/>
    </Insert2>
    <Insert2 I2attr1="A222C" I2attr2 ="456">
    <sub ID="1BC"/>
    </Insert2>
</Main>
</FIXML>
```

From this I need to check the mandatory sections are present or not if not present then have to add them by self closing the tag.

After the `<Hdr ..>` element check `<Insert1../>` element is there or not, if present keep that section as is, if not present then have to add `<Insert1/>` self close tag after the `<Hdr ..>` element, then check for `<Insert2.../>` if present keep that element after `<Insert1 .../>` or `<Insert1/>` if not present add  after the `<Insert1/>`.

To form an xml like this.

```
<FIXML v="4.4" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Main attr1="19000" attr2="10">
        <Hdr hattr1="ABC" hattr2="DEF"/>
        <Insert1/>
        <Insert2>
        <sub/>
        </Insert2>
        <Insert2>
        <sub/>
        </Insert2>
    </Main>
    </FIXML>
```

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to validate the existence of only the first order child nodes present within "Main" node? And more importantly your xml has to a valid xml to xslt transformation, which is not the case

Comment: Hi Saurav.Yes correct all under the <Main> element tag, ok I am showing the element will have many attributes with in the element(Main,Hdr etc.,)

Comment: please note that the xml has to be a valid xml to XSLT

Comment: Please don't post any code data in comment.Edit your question section

Comment: I have placed the correct formatted xml file in the main post. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there different ways how you can achieve what you want depending upon xslt version that you are using.
I have used XSLT 1.0.
From what you asked I have assumed the order of element arrangement and elements are pre-known to you.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:FIXML="fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="FIXML msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="checkData">
    <data>Hdr</data>
    <data>Insert1</data>
    <data>Insert2</data>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="FIXML:Main">
    <Main>
      <xsl:variable name="temp" select="//*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($checkData)/*">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="count($temp[local-name(.)=current()]) &gt;= 1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$temp[local-name(.)=current()]"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{current()}"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Main>
  </xsl:template>
```

Variable "checkData" contains the element list you need to check already arranged. only other thing is that you have to use node-set function of your XSLT parser

Comment: Thank you. I tried the same XSLT file in OSB transformation. I got the below error. Error executing the XSLT transformation: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: For extension function, could not find method weblogic.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeIterator.node-set([ExpressionContext,] ).

Comment: you have to find an equivalent node-set() function within your xslt parser

Comment: if you can, use XSLT 2.0, it has support for node-set() (aka, you could iterate directly on variable nodes, no need to use a node-set() function).

Comment: thanks Eric, OSB (Oracle Service Bus) supports XSLT 1.0 version only.

Comment: Arf, sorry for this useless comment then :-s

Comment: Any help on this with relate to OSB XSLT check.